# Can I use a resource string for a package name?

Tags: android, android-manifest, package

Is something like this possible?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="@string/package_name"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="@string/version_name">
```

The code above gives me an error:

> C:\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:539: Application package
>   '@string/package_name' must have a minimum of 2 segments.

My strings are defined in res/strings.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My app</string>
    <string name="version_name">1.00</string>
    <string name="package_name">com.mycompany.myapp</string>
```

If I replace `@string/package_name` with the name of the package, `android:versionName` seems to be set correctly. 
So the question is why package name doesn't work while `android:versionName` works?

**Edit:**
Is there any way to use a package name specified in external file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, you may only access XML resources using the `@resource/name` format for attributes defined in the `android` xmlns (`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`).

As package is not defined in the android schema, it cannot access resources that way, while versionName can.

Comment: Is there any other way to use package name string from external file?

Comment: @Lev Not that I am aware of, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

@Lev I know its very late, but it may help others.

I am also wanted to use `@string/package_name` in some cases.
I am getting it done by creating string resource in `app/build.gradle` like below.

```
defaultConfig {
    // your other code
    applicationId 'com.example'
    resValue "string", "package_name", applicationId
    // your other code
}
```