# Android 11 declaring package visibility in Android Manifest with string resource

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-11

My app detects if a certain app is installed via `queryIntentActivities`. Since my app targets api level 30 this [stopped working](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) because I was missing some manifest declarations.

In [this example](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#package-name) they define the package name directly. But the apps I want to query for differ for each build variant. So it would be better to use a string resource. However this doesn't seem possible.

**Example**

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.store" />
        <package android:name="com.example.services" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

**What I would like**

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="@string/store_app" />
        <package android:name="@string/services_app" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

*Some other file*

```
<string name="store_app">com.example.store</string>
<string name="services_app">com.example.services</string>
```

How to use a string resource

Comment: You could use the packages names directly as in the example, but override the Manifest file for each build, so each will have the correct list of queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it with [manifestPlaceholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) because I wanted to have a single AndroidManifest. The only downside to this solution is that I also use the app package names in my code and therefore I need to define it once more in a string resource file.

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="${store_app}" />
        <package android:name="${services_app}" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
manifestPlaceholders = [store_app: "com.example.store"]
```

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51338664/2212770) to create a string resource in my gradle file, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Any idea on how to get packages like - com.companyName.* ??
there can be multiple packages with the same prefix but different suffix.